# Did someone generate with doxygen a HTML documentation from a Thrift Idl?

Tags: html, documentation, doxygen, thrift, idl

I'm trying to generate an html documentation file from a Thrift IDL.
This is the example.idl
[image]

The generated html is like this:

[image]

There is a warning:
example.idl:1: warning: Member pad0 (variable) of class Session is not documented.

Does anyone know how I can generate the documentation correctly?

Thank you in advance.

1. doxygen 1.8.15
2. This is a thrift idl file with a ; at the end of a variable definition
   [example.zip](https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/files/3256462/example.zip)
3. This is the original thrift idl file
   [example-original.zip](https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/files/3256465/example-original.zip)
4. This is the configuration file
   [Doxyfile.zip](https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/files/3256469/Doxyfile.zip)
5. thrift 0.11.0 can generate an HTML documentation
   `thrift -gen html yourfile.thrift`
   but thrift 0.12.0 can not, this is the output

> [WARNING:generation:1] Unable to get a generator for "html"
>
> [WARNING:generation:1] Unable to get a generator for "html:standalone".

Comment: To be able to look into the problem some more information is needed. Which doxygen version did you use? Which changes are in your Doxyfile compared to the default Doxyfile? Please present a small complete problem (MWE) showing the problem.

Comment: Cross posted as an issue https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/issues/7029 as well.

Comment: Not sure if it helps, but Thrift also can generate HTML: try `thrift -gen html yourfile.thrift`.

Answer (score 0):

As [@albert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1657886/albert) say here [doxygen 7029](https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/issues/7029)

There are a few ways to have doxygen understand it e.g.:

- Create (and maintain) an INPUT_FILTER (/ FILTER_PATTERNS) filter that converts the Apache Thrift IDL format to a format that is understood by doxygen

> This can in principle be written in any language, the user must have the possibility to start it (so might need to install some packages for it). For some hints in this direction see http://www.doxygen.nl/helpers.html

- write (and maintain) a separate parser ('scanner' and 'code') for it.

> See the existing scanners / code parsers in the src directory of doxygen
>
> There are a couple of languages that use their own parsers a.o. Fortran, python, vhdl.